# How to do a pagination from array?

Tags: php, pagination

I have an array with the data which I want to display with pagination.

```
$display_array = Array
(
    [0] => "0602 xxx2",
    [1] => "0602 xxx3",
    [2] => 5 // Total= 2+3
    [3] => "0602 xxx3",
    [4] => "0602 saa4",
    [5] => 7 // Total = 3+4
)
```

I have try some thing like this

```
function pagination($display_array, $page)
{   
    global $show_per_page;
    $page = $page < 1 ? 1 : $page;
    $start = ($page - 1) * $show_per_page;
    $end = $page * $show_per_page;
    for($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
    {
        ////echo $display_array[$i] . "<p>";
        // How to manipulate this?   
        // To get the result as I described below.
    }
}
```

I want do a pagination to get the expected result like this:

If I define `$show_per_page = 2;` then `pagination($display_array, 1);` outputs:

```
0602 xxx2
0602 xxxx3
Total:5
```

And `paganation($display_array, 2);` outputs:

```
0602 xxx3
0602 saa4
Total:7
```

If I define `$show_per_page = 3;`, then `pagination($display_array, 1);` outputs:

```
0602 xxx2
0602 xxxx3
Total: 5 
0602 xxx3
```

And `paganation($display_array, 2);` outputs:

```
0602 saa4
Total:7
```

If I define `$show_per_page = 4;` outputs:

```
0602 xxx2
0602 xxxx3
Total:5
0602 xxx3
0602 saa4
Total: 7
```

Comment: So what's your question? Or are you just looking for somebody to do your work?

Comment: Can you describe what do you want to manipulate?

Comment: $end = $start + $show_per_page; surely?

Comment: $end = $page * $show_per_page;

Comment: @python - I can see what you have in your code. Is there any particular reason why you're setting $end this way? It means that you'll get a different number of entries displayed on every single page

Comment: @Mark Baker the idea is to do pagantion from the array.it mean how many elements we want to show per page,$page = $_GET['page'].

Comment: Or you have any idea to do this?Mark Baker.thanks

Comment: @python - I understand what pagination is, and I understand that you want to do it from the array rather than from the database... what I don't understand is your logic with the number of entries to appear on each page. If $show_per_page is 2, you get page 1 is entries 0-2, which is 3 entries, not 2.

Comment: @Mark Baker yes,You are right,In the case the total may not call entry.But How Can we display total when we do paganation,because as you see the total appear many times .If you have better solution to do this ,please let me know,I will change.thank you very much for your investigate.

Comment: I wouldn't store these page totals in the array... I'd store purely the underlying data in the array, and calculate the totals at each page request.

Comment: But What you will do with Total if $show_per_page = 4;(you can look my above description in the case $show_per_page = 4)

Comment: I'd extract the 4 rows to display, then do the totalling during my render loop, and manually display the total as a final line

Comment: sound great,.Now I change the data structure ,Please you help me here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796007/how-to-do-pagination-from-multiple-array-and-calculate-the-total

Comment: After you feedback I have changed my data structure ,hope this will got from your help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796007/how-to-do-pagination-from-multiple-array-and-calculate-the-total

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
    function paganation($display_array, $page) {
        global $show_per_page;

        $page = $page < 1 ? 1 : $page;

        // start position in the $display_array
        // +1 is to account for total values.
        $start = ($page - 1) * ($show_per_page + 1);
        $offset = $show_per_page + 1;

        $outArray = array_slice($display_array, $start, $offset);

        var_dump($outArray);
    }

    $show_per_page = 2;

    paganation($display_array, 1);
    paganation($display_array, 2);


    $show_per_page = 3;
    paganation($display_array, 1);
    paganation($display_array, 2);
```

The output is:

```
// when $show_per_page = 2;
array
  0 => string '0602 xxx2' (length=9)
  1 => string '0602 xxx3' (length=9)
  2 => int 5
array
  0 => string '0602 xxx3' (length=9)
  1 => string '0602 saa4' (length=9)
  2 => int 7

// when $show_per_page = 3;
array
  0 => string '0602 xxx2' (length=9)
  1 => string '0602 xxx3' (length=9)
  2 => int 5
  3 => string '0602 xxx3' (length=9)
array
  0 => string '0602 saa4' (length=9)
  1 => int 7
```

The output for $show_per_page = 3 is different than yours, but I'm not sure what you expect? You want to fetch everything that is left (i.e. '0602 saa4' and 7) plus one previous element (i.e. '0602 xxx3')?

Comment: for other case ok,but I have test ,$show_per_page = 4 I did not get the total.

Comment: and $show_per_page = 1 I got two entris display,in fact it should only one entry .

Comment: And Why you $offset = $show_per_page + 1;Because it is not always like this .Marcin

Comment: @python. if you have $show_per_page = 2 that you return 3 elements of your array. If you have $show_per_page = 3 than you want  4 elements. But when show_per_page = 4 you want 6 elements? Why 6 not 5? I don't understand how this pagination should work.

Comment: anywhere you gave me the tips,Maybe I have make the question again with good data structure than this.thank you so much,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796007/how-to-do-pagination-from-multiple-array-and-calculate-the-total

Answer (score 7):

Use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
function paginate($array, $pageSize, $page = 1)
{
    $pages = array_chunk($array, $pageSize);
    return $page > sizeof($pages) ? [] : $pages[$page - 1];
}
```

or use a cleaner version of Marcin's Answer:

```
function paginate($array, $pageSize, $page = 1)
{
    $page = $page < 1 ? 1 : $page;
    $start = ($page - 1) * $pageSize;
    return array_slice($array, $start, $pageSize);
}
```

or in PHP 7

```
function paginate($array, $pageSize, $page = 1)
{
    $pages = array_chunk($array, $pageSize);
    return $pages[$page - 1] ?? [] ;
}
```

Comment: the array_chunk idea is very nice, thanks for that . . . now to build a menu system based on this. :)

Answer (score 0):

$output = array_slice($inputArray,$page-1,$showPerPage); 
$output will contain the desired interval.
$total = sizeof($inputArray); /*the total items in the array*/

Comment: why total = sizeof($inputArray);?