# How to do pagination from multiple array and calculate the total?

Tags: php

I have an array that present the data will be use to display as paganation.

```
$display_array = Array (
              [0] => Array
                  (
                  [0] => 1
                  [1] => 2
                  [2] => 5
                  [3] => 5
                  )

              [1] => Array
                  (
                  [0] => 1
                  [1] => 2
                  [2] => 5
                  [3] => 5
                  )

              [2] => Array
                  (
                  [0] => 1
                  [1] => 2
                  )

              [3] => Array
                  (
                  [0] => 1
                  [1] => 2
                  )

            )
```

I WANT DO A PAGANATION GET THE EXPECTED RESULT LIKE THIS:

IF I defined $show_per_page = `2`;

call paganation($display_array,1);//page 1 firstpage OUTPUT :

```
1
2
```

call  paganation($display_array,2);//next page 2 OUTPUT :

```
    5
    5
  Total:13 // total appear here 


....//next page n
```

IF I defined $show_per_page = `3`;

paganation($display_array,1);//page 1 firstpage OUTPUT:

```
   1
   2
   5
```

paganation($display_array,2);//next page 2 OUTPUT :

```
  5
  Total:13//Now total appear here
  1
  2
```

paganation($display_array,3);//next page 3 OUTPUT :

```
 5
 5
 Total:10 // total appear here 
 1
```

IF I defined $show_per_page = `12`;
call paganation($display_array,1);//page 1 firstpage OUTPUT :

```
1
2
5
5
total:13 // total here
1
2
5
5
total:13 // total here
1
2
total:3 //total
1
2
total:3 //total
```

People here have any idea?

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to achieve by posting 2 similar questions? Just stick to your original question and modify that one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793997/how-to-do-a-pagination-from-array

Comment: yes,But I found that I have to change my data structure .So I'll have no problems when the case for example $show_per_page = 12.one more I got the suggestion to change the input array ,at this time people will be understand what I want ,I got a good answer :) And Did you understand my question right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something naive (because it doesn't skip the first few pages efficiently):

```
// array to display
// page to show (1-indexed)
// number of items to show per page
function pagination($display_array, $page, $show_per_page){
    $start = $show_per_page * ($page-1);
    $end   = $show_per_page * $page;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($display_array as $section){
        $total = 0;
        foreach($section as $value){
            if($i >= $end){
                break 2; // break out of both loops
            }

            $total += $value;
            if($i >= $start){
                echo $value.'<br>';
            }
            $i++;
        }
        if($i >= $start){
            echo 'total:'.$total.'<br>';
        }
        if($i >= $end){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```