# Parsing XML file after converting to json with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, xml

I have an XML url that I need to parse and paginate on a jquery ajax request. I'm not too much experience in PHP and I'm trying to figure out how I can get the values of each item? Also, how might I be able to search through the results for a match?

My code:

```
$xmlFile = simplexml_load_file($xmlURL);
$json = json_encode($xmlFile);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);



echo "<pre>";



foreach ($array['item'] as $item) {
    $title = $item['title'];
    $date = $item['date'];






   echo "<div id='event-item'>";
   echo "<span id='title'>" . $title . "</span>" . "<br />";
   echo "<span id='date'>" . $date . "</span><br/>";
   echo "</div>";
}
```

The output (trying to traverse and search through this):

```
Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => English Matters Book Group for English Language Learners
                    [date] => Wednesday, June 15, 2016
                    [time] => 10:00 AM 


ib=0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Teen Advisory Board (TAB)
                    [date] => Wednesday, June 15, 2016
                    [time] => 5:30 PM
                    [enddate] => Array
                        (
                        )
```

Comment: Could you show a second item to your array output?

Comment: Not sure the context of this. If you're asking about your answer below - yes. However, in the case of my code above, I've added to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard foreach loop would suffice:

```
<?php
foreach ($array['item'] as $item) {
    echo $item['title'] . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! any advice on how I can go about paginating these results? I'm trying to get them to display based on a date selected on a datepicker and paginate.

Comment: You could swap it for a `for` loop and calculate how many rows per page

Comment: Fair enough. Any good resources on this? I can only seem to find stuff geared towards mysql rather than xml.

Comment: Better yet. How to search through this for a certain value?

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451362/how-to-add-php-pagination-in-arrays) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793997/how-to-do-a-pagination-from-array) or [here](http://lotsofcode.com/php-array-pagination/) for pagination. Regarding search: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: Tried using in_array and array_search with no luck.

Comment: Perhaps start a new question with your array search question, showing what you've tried