# how to create pagination using variable

Tags: pagination

I have a variable that contains array. 
my variable is name is product and it contains product name, product image, product description as array.
I have 1000 number of products.

I want to **paginate without SQL** because I am using web-service to pull the product details.

I tried array_slice to slice the variable count and put the next variable count in for loop. I want to put it in pagination.
Please help.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these links :

[How to add PHP pagination in array's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451362/how-to-add-php-pagination-in-arrays)

[How to do a pagination from array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793997/how-to-do-a-pagination-from-array)

https://github.com/lotsofcode/php-array-pagination/blob/master/example.php